# How to solve the problem of memory slowly getting larger？

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a .net framework WinForms project for IR camera temperature measurement. I checked the memory with the performance monitor and found that after about 12 hours of running, the memory seems to be slowly getting larger. Since the project needed to run steadily over time, I was concerned that the constant increase in memory would eventually cause the system to crash.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

## Code

```
    `if(pictureBox1.Image != null && pictureBox1!=null)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        if(Count>1000)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            Count = 0;
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = MatImageShow.ToBitmap();`
```

## IR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo5wa.png)

## 12 Hours ago

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24SRp.png)

## 12 Hours later

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKhhz.png)

Comment: [Memory profile](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/choosing-a-net-memory-profiler-in-visual-studio-part-1/) your program.

Comment: How does Count get incremented so that you actually enter the inner `if` statement?

Comment: `&& pictureBox1!=null` in `if(pictureBox1.Image != null && pictureBox1!=null)` makes little sense, since expressions are evaluated left-to-right. Therefore `&& pictureBox1!=null` is not guarding anything; because if _pictureBox1_ happens to be _null_, `pictureBox1.Image != null` will throw first before `pictureBox1!=null` got a chance to be evaluated...

Comment: `pictureBox1?.Image?.Dispose()` -- You don't need to call `GC.Collect()` -- This: `MatImageShow.ToBitmap();`, generates a copy. What happens to the original?